# Outputting to a file

Tags: python

code snippet:

```
def after_equals(s):
    return s.partition(' = ')[-1]
for k,s in zip(keyword, score):
  print after_equals(k) + ',' + after_equals(s)
```

The output of the code prints:

```
NORTH,88466
GUESS,83965
DRESSES,79379
RALPH,74897
MATERIAL,68168
```

I need to output the into file. Please advice how to write to a file.

Comment: What has this to do with your code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a file in write mode and write a string to the file, then close it:

```
f = file('myfile.txt','w')
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

For your case:

```
def after_equals(s):
    return s.partition(' = ')[-1]
f = file('myfile.txt','w')
for k,s in zip(keyword, score):
  f.write('%s,%s\n' % (after_equals(k), after_equals(s)))
f.close()
```

Comment: It prints only one line if file and throws ValueError: I/O operation on closed file in console

Comment: maybe you called the f.close() inside the loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(filename, 'w') as out:
    for k,s in zip(keyword, score):
        print >> out, after_equals(k) + ',' + after_equals(s)
        # note:  ^^^
```